# How to access complex nested json in ember.js

Tags: ember.js

after thorough searching stackoverflow and reading through all of the documetation on emberjs.com I'm finding myself stuck. I have a complex json object that I'm trying to model and output in my ember project. 
I don't have control over the JSON, otherwise I'd change it's format to be easier digested. That said, here is my problem.

I have the following json

```
[
{
    "id":1,
    "catId": "10051",
    "catUrl": "path/to/location",
    "childCount": "4",
    "description": [{
        "text": "Description Text"
    }],
    "identifier": "UNQ123456",
    "partialResults": "false"
}
]
```

What I'm trying to get at is the text value in description. I've tried creating the hasMany and belongsTo nested model construct described on emberjs.com, as well as many other patterns that were described as answers here on stack overflow, yet none of them seem to work or match the data construct I have to work with. 
I've even tried the anonymous function in the first block of code on this page. http://emberjs.com/guides/models/defining-models/ trying to traverse this to the text that I want.

Regardless, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a custom data transform to handle your special JSON field. This can be done by using the `DS.RESTAdapter.registerTransform` function. Something like this should work for your use case:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.registerTransform('descriptionText', {
  serialize: function(data) {
    var text = data[0].text;
    return text;
  },
  deserialize: function(text) {
    var data = [Ember.create({text: text})];
    return data;
  }
});
```

And then use it as a custom attribute for your model:

```
App.MyModel = DS.Model.extend({
  ...
  description: DS.attr('descriptionText')
});
```

Note that the name of the transform could be something else as `descriptionText` as long you use the same name for `DS.attr(...)`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This has been removed from Ember Data Beta 1.0 beta 1. The documentation offers some alternative approaches, see https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#json-transforms